# ListView doesn't refresh when I delete something

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I have an custom adapter that is giving me problem. When I add or edit something it updates the listview but when I delete it doesn't.

Code when I remove something:

```
private ArrayList<Teams> m_orders = null;
private TeamsAdapter m_adapter;
private ListView lstv;
...
private void deleteTeam(int indexRemove){
    hasKeys.remove(hasKeys.indexOf(m_orders.get(indexRemove).getTeamName()));
    Menu.teams.remove(m_orders.get(indexRemove).getTeamName());
    m_orders.remove(indexRemove);
    m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I tried use a Runnable, but without success.

```
 private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
        }
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

My onCreate method:

```
    lstv = findViewById(R.id.teamsList);
    m_orders = new ArrayList<Teams>();
    this.m_adapter = new TeamsAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_orders);
    lstv.setAdapter(this.m_adapter);
```

Comment: I think you are trying to remove an item from the ArrayList which is outside the adapter class. you need to write a delete function inside the adapter class to delete an item from the ArrayList that is used in that adapter class.

Comment: @NishikantoSarkarSimul Worked, thanks, can you, please, answer so I can mark as solved?

Comment: you are welcome. I have given an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove an item from the ArrayList which is inside the Adapter class. So you need to write your delete function inside the adapter class. In this way will able to delete items and update listview by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an `m_adapter` with `m_orders` dataset, but you are removing item from `m_teams` dataset, make no sense, they are different instances.

```
final List<Teams> mTeams = new ArrayList<>();
TeamsAdapter mAdapter;

onCreate() {
    mAdapter = new TeamsAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mTeams);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.teamsList);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

addTeams(Collection<Teams> items) {
    mTeams.addAll(items);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

deleteTeam(int index) {
   mTeams.remove(index);
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: That was my mistake, but, with m_orders in all, the problem keeps